# Multiple time call onBindViewHolder method when firebase Documentlistener call in this method in kotlin(infinite call)

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This is adapterclass of Reyclerview My question is when I am calling firebase document in onBindViewHolder method it callining infinte loop due to call back of addSnapshotListener becuse I need to data reflect instantly when firebase addsnapshot litener and set into specific text view. where I am already set on my old project working fine but now it's not working.

```
package com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.adapter

import android.content.res.ColorStateListimport android.text.TextUtilsimport android.util.Logimport android.view.LayoutInflaterimport android.view.Viewimport android.view.ViewGroupimport androidx.core.content.ContextCompatimport androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerViewimport com.bumptech.glide.Glideimport com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreimport com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistrationimport com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorageimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.Rimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.databinding.LayoutHomeItemBindingimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.model.HomeMatchimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.model.Scoreimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.utils.Constantsimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.utils.Constants.TAGimport com.wedoapps.cricketLiveLine.utils.ShowLogToastimport java.text.SimpleDateFormatimport java.util.Calendarimport java.util.Locale

class HomeCardAdapter(private val listener: SetOnClick,private val homeMatchArrayList: ArrayList<HomeMatch>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCardAdapter.HomeCardViewHolder>() {

private var binderCounter = 0
private var createCounter = 0
val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
var fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private var  fireStoreRef = fireStore.collection(Constants.collectionPathMatchList)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeCardViewHolder {

    ShowLogToast.showLog("Counter for OnCreateViewHolder-->", createCounter.toString())
    createCounter++


    val binding =
        LayoutHomeItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return HomeCardViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeCardViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val currentItem = homeMatchArrayList[position]

    ShowLogToast.showLog("Counter for onBindViewHolder-->", binderCounter.toString())
    binderCounter++


    with(holder) {

        binding.tvMatch.text = currentItem.matchDetail?.trim()

        if (currentItem.matchDate == null) {
            binding.tvTime.text = currentItem.currentDate?.trim()
        } else {
            fun Long?.getDateMatchList(): String {
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)
                val cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
                cal.timeInMillis = this?.times(1000L) ?: 0L
                return sdf.format(cal.time)
            }
            binding.tvTime.text = currentItem.matchDate.getDateMatchList()
        }




        when (currentItem.matchStatus) {
            Constants.statusUpcoming -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "UP: $currentItem")
                binding.tvOver.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.tvFInn.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.tvSecondFInn.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.tvSecondOver.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.tvFirstTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvDayStatus.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.relativeBottom.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btmDiv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvDayStatus.text = currentItem.venue?.trim()
                binding.tvMatchStatus.text = Constants.statusUpcoming
                binding.tvMatchStatus.backgroundTintList =
                    ColorStateList.valueOf(itemView.context.getColor(R.color.yellow_orange))
                binding.tvFirstTeam.text =
                    if (currentItem.fullNameTeam1.isNullOrEmpty()) currentItem.team1?.trim() else currentItem.fullNameTeam1!!.trim()
                binding.tvSecondTeam.text =
                    if (currentItem.fullNameTeam2.isNullOrEmpty()) currentItem.team2?.trim() else currentItem.fullNameTeam2!!.trim()
                binding.tvFirstTeam.maxLines = 3
                binding.tvSecondTeam.maxLines = 3
                binding.tvFirstTeam.setLineSpacing(0.8f, 0.8f)
                binding.tvSecondTeam.setLineSpacing(0.8f, 0.8f)
            }

            Constants.statusCompleted -> {
                binding.tvFInn.maxLines = 1
                binding.tvSecondFInn.maxLines = 1
                binding.tvFInn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvOver.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondFInn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondOver.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvFirstTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btmDiv.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.tvDayStatus.visibility = View.GONE

                binding.tvMatchStatus.text = buildString {
                    append("Finished")
                }
                binding.relativeBottom.visibility = View.GONE

                binding.tvMatchStatus.backgroundTintList =
                    ColorStateList.valueOf(itemView.context.getColor(R.color.green))
                binding.tvFirstTeam.text =
                    if (currentItem.codeTeam1.isNullOrEmpty()) currentItem.team1?.trim() else currentItem.codeTeam1!!.trim()
                binding.tvSecondTeam.text =
                    if (currentItem.codeTeam2.isNullOrEmpty()) currentItem.team2?.trim() else currentItem.codeTeam2!!.trim()
            }

            Constants.statusLive -> {
                binding.tvFInn.maxLines = 1
                binding.tvSecondFInn.maxLines = 1
                binding.tvFInn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvOver.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondFInn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondOver.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvFirstTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvSecondTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvDayStatus.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.relativeBottom.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btmDiv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvMatchStatus.text = buildString {
                    append("◉ LIVE")
                }
                binding.tvMatchStatus.backgroundTintList =
                    ColorStateList.valueOf(itemView.context.getColor(R.color.colorRed))
                binding.tvFirstTeam.text =
                    if (currentItem.codeTeam1.isNullOrEmpty()) currentItem.team1?.trim() else currentItem.codeTeam1!!.trim()
                binding.tvSecondTeam.text =
                    if (currentItem.codeTeam2.isNullOrEmpty()) currentItem.team2?.trim() else currentItem.codeTeam2!!.trim()
            }

            else -> {
                binding.tvMatchStatus.text = currentItem.matchStatus?.trim()
            }

        }


        val imgPlayerDrawableDefault =
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.imgpsh_fullsize_anim)

        val fileReference1 =
            storageRef.child(Constants.flagIconPath + currentItem.team1?.trim { it <= ' ' } + ".png")


        fileReference1.metadata.addOnSuccessListener {

            if (it.name != null && it.sizeBytes > 0) {
                fileReference1.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "TeamH1URL: $uri")
                    Glide.with(itemView.context)
                        .load(uri)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.imgpsh_fullsize_anim)
                        .into(binding.ivFirstTeam)
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    binding.ivFirstTeam.setImageDrawable(
                        imgPlayerDrawableDefault
                    )
                }
            }

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            ShowLogToast.showLog("Storage Exception Team1 flag-->", it.localizedMessage)

        }


        val fileReference2 =
            storageRef.child(Constants.flagIconPath + currentItem.team2?.trim { it <= ' ' } + ".png")

        fileReference2.metadata.addOnSuccessListener {

            if (it.name != null && it.sizeBytes > 0) {
                fileReference2.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "TeamH2URL: $uri")
                    Glide.with(itemView.context)
                        .load(uri)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.imgpsh_fullsize_anim)
                        .into(binding.ivSecondTeam)
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    binding.ivSecondTeam.setImageDrawable(
                        imgPlayerDrawableDefault
                    )
                }


            }

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            ShowLogToast.showLog("Storage Exception Team2 flag-->", it.localizedMessage)
        }


       fireStoreRef.document(currentItem.id!!).collection(Constants.lastBallInfoKey)
            .document(Constants.lbdKey)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen Failed", error)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (value != null) {
                    val data = value.data
                    if (data != null) {
                        val ballByBall: String = data[Constants.ballByBallKey] as String
                        Log.d(TAG, "LBD: $data")

                        binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = ballByBall

                        when {

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("0 Run") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = "0"
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("1 Run") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = "1"
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("2 Run") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = "2"
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("3 Run") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = "3"
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("It's 6") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = "6-6-6"
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("It's 4") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = "4-4-4"
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("WD + 1") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = buildString {
                                    append("WD1")
                                }
                            }

                            ballByBall.contentEquals("WD + 2") -> {
                                binding.txtBallByBallUpdate.text = buildString {
                                    append("WD2")
                                }
                            }

                        }


                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No Data")
                }
            }

        fireStoreRef.document(currentItem.id!!).collection(Constants.matchRateKey)
            .document(Constants.matchKey)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen Failed", error)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (value != null) {
                    val data = value.data
                    if (data != null) {

                        val it = data.toString()
                        val value1 = it.substring(1, it.length - 1)
                        val keyValuePair = value1.split(",")
                        val map = hashMapOf<String, String>()

                        keyValuePair.forEach { text ->
                            val entry = text.split("=")
                            map[entry[0].trim()] = entry[1].trim()
                        }

                        val favTeam = map[Constants.favTeamKey]?.trim()
                        val rate1 = map[Constants.rate1Key]?.trim()
                        val rate2 = map[Constants.rate2Key]?.trim()



                        when (currentItem.matchStatus) {
                            Constants.statusUpcoming -> {
                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(favTeam)) {
                                    binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.GONE
                                } else {
                                    binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    binding.tvFavTeam.text = favTeam
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rate1)) {
                                    binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.GONE
                                } else {
                                    binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    binding.tvRate1.text = rate1
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rate2)) {
                                    binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.GONE
                                } else {
                                    binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    binding.tvRate2.text = rate2
                                }

                            }

                            Constants.statusLive -> {
                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(favTeam)) {
                                    binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.GONE
                                } else {
                                    binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    binding.tvFavTeam.text = favTeam
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rate1)) {
                                    binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.GONE
                                } else {
                                    binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    binding.tvRate1.text = rate1
                                }

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rate2)) {
                                    binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.GONE
                                } else {
                                    binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    binding.tvRate2.text = rate2
                                }

                            }

                            Constants.statusCompleted -> {
                                binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.GONE
                                binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.GONE
                                binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.GONE

                            }

                        }




                        Log.d(TAG, "mr: $data")
                    } else {

                        binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.GONE

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No Data")

                    binding.tvFavTeam.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.tvRate2.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.tvRate1.visibility = View.GONE


                }
            }




        fireStoreRef.document(currentItem.id!!).collection(Constants.collectionPathLiveMatch)
            .document(Constants.runRateInfoKey)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen Failed", error)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (value != null) {
                    val data = value.data
                    if (data != null) {
                        val it = data.toString()
                        val value1 = it.substring(1, it.length - 1)
                        val keyValuePair = value1.split(",")
                        val map = hashMapOf<String, String>()

                        keyValuePair.forEach { text ->
                            val entry = text.split("=")
                            map[entry[0].trim()] = entry[1].trim()
                        }

                        binding.tvDayStatus.text = if (map[Constants.otherInfoKey]?.trim()
                                .isNullOrEmpty() || map[Constants.otherInfoKey].equals("") || map[Constants.otherInfoKey].equals(
                                "-"
                            )
                        ) if (currentItem.venue.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${currentItem.venue}" else map[Constants.otherInfoKey]?.trim()
                        Log.d(TAG, "getRunRate: $data")



                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No Data")
                }
            }


        fireStoreRef.document(currentItem.id!!.toString())
            .collection(Constants.collectionPathLiveMatch).document(Constants.scoreTeam1Key)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen Failed", error)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (value != null) {
                    val allTeam1 = value.toObject(Score::class.java)
                    binding.tvFInn.text = value.get(Constants.scoreKey).toString().trim()
                    binding.tvOver.text = buildString {
                        append("( ")
                        append(value.get(Constants.overKey).toString())
                        append(" )")
                    }

                    //val allTeam1 = ArrayList<Score>()
                    //allTeam1?.add(allTeam1)

                    Log.d(TAG, "team1 HomeCard: $allTeam1")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No Data")
                }


            }




        fireStoreRef.document(currentItem.id!!.toString())
            .collection(Constants.collectionPathLiveMatch).document(Constants.scoreTeam2Key)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen Failed", error)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (value != null) {
                    val allTeam2 = value.toObject(Score::class.java)
                    binding.tvSecondFInn.text = value.get(Constants.scoreKey).toString().trim()
                    binding.tvSecondOver.text = buildString {
                        append("( ")
                        append(value.get(Constants.overKey).toString())
                        append(" )")
                    }


                    Log.d(TAG, "team2: $allTeam2")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No Data")
                }
            }





    }


}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    ShowLogToast.showLog("HomeCardAdapter size-->", homeMatchArrayList.size.toString())
    return homeMatchArrayList.size
    // return differ.currentList.size
}

override fun onViewRecycled(holder: HomeCardViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    val position: Int = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition

}
inner class HomeCardViewHolder(var binding: LayoutHomeItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    init {
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            val position = absoluteAdapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                val item = homeMatchArrayList[position]
                listener.onClick(item)
            }
        }
    }


}


/*  private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HomeMatch>() {
      override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: HomeMatch, newItem: HomeMatch) =
          oldItem.id == newItem.id

      override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: HomeMatch, newItem: HomeMatch) =
          oldItem.id == newItem.id
  }

  val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)*/

interface SetOnClick {
    fun onClick(match: HomeMatch)
}

}
```

`

This is my fragment calss where to Calling and refeleing of list. I am verify that the issue is on adapter class not fragment calss. debug and also print the log to check thrice.

`
class HomeMatchListFragment : BaseFragment(), View.OnClickListener, HomeCardAdapter.SetOnClick {
private val tagHomeMatch: String = "HomeMatchListFragment"
private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentHomeMatchListBinding

```
private var mContext: Context? = null
private var dialog: Dialog? = null
private lateinit var viewModel: CricketGuruViewModel

private val fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private val firestorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
private val storageRef = firestorage.reference

private var permissionChecker: PermissionChecker? = null

private lateinit var matchScoreListAdapter: HomeCardAdapter

private var team1 = ArrayList<String>()
private var team2 = ArrayList<String>()
private var homeMatchArrayList: ArrayList<HomeMatch> = ArrayList()

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mContext = context
    permissionChecker = PermissionChecker(mContext!!)

}

override fun getInflateResource(): Int {
    return R.layout.fragment_home_match_list
}

override fun displayMessage(message: String) {
    mBinding.root.snack(message)
}

override fun initView() {
    mBinding = getBinding()
    viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
    setRecyclerView()


}

override fun postInit() {

}

override fun handleListener() {
}

override fun initProgressBar() {
    dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
    dialog!!.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress)
    dialog!!.setCancelable(false)
}

override fun showLoadingIndicator(isShow: Boolean) {
    dialog!!.isVisible(isShow, dialog)
}


private fun setRecyclerView() {

    matchScoreListAdapter = HomeCardAdapter(this,homeMatchArrayList)

    val mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.adapter = matchScoreListAdapter


    // Set the RecyclerViewPool to the RecyclerViews
    mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.recycledViewPool.clear()

    showShimmerViewVisibility(true)

    var count =0
    viewModel.getAllMatch().observe(this) {
       // matchScoreListAdapter.differ.submitList(it?.toMutableList())

        count++
        ShowLogToast.showLog(tagHomeMatch, "Count is-->$count")
        homeMatchArrayList.clear()
        homeMatchArrayList.addAll(it)

        if (it.size > 0) {
           // matchScoreListAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,homeMatchArrayList.size)
            setRecyclerViewVisibility(true)
        } else {
            setRecyclerViewVisibility(false)
        }

        showShimmerViewVisibility(false)

        ShowLogToast.showLog("Test Home Array Size", it.size.toString())
    }

    if(homeMatchArrayList.size >0){
         matchScoreListAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,homeMatchArrayList.size)
    }



}


private fun showShimmerViewVisibility(b: Boolean) {
    if (b) {
        mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.showShimmerAdapter()
    } else {
        mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.hideShimmerAdapter()

    }
}
private fun setRecyclerViewVisibility(b: Boolean) {
    if (b) {
        mBinding.txtNoDataHomeLiveMatchList.visibility = View.GONE
        mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        mBinding.recyclerViewHomeLiveMatchList.visibility = View.GONE
        mBinding.txtNoDataHomeLiveMatchList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}


override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v!!.id) {
        /* R.id.linearHomeAdsLiveMatch->{
             CommonUtils.gotoAdsContact(mContext!!)

         }*/
    }

}

override fun onClick(match: HomeMatch) {
    val intentHomeFragment = Intent(requireActivity(), ViewPagerActivity::class.java)
    intentHomeFragment.putExtra("match", match)
    startActivity(intentHomeFragment)
}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (homeMatchArrayList.size > 0) {
        matchScoreListAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, homeMatchArrayList.size)
    }

}

}
```

This is adapterclass of Reyclerview My question is when I am calling firebase document in onBindViewHolder method it callining infinte loop due to call back of addSnapshotListener becuse I need to data reflect instantly when firebase addsnapshot litener and set into specific text view. where I am already set on my old project working fine but now it's not working.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700** (seven hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

First of all move your listeners out of viewHolders, never set firebase listener or any kind of service in Adapters/ViewHolders,
ViewHolders/Adapters should be responsible for only creating and binding views they must not be aware of data service from where data is coming.
try this it will fix everything

Comment: but we getting that data on arraylist from onviewBindholder                                          val currentItem = homeMatchArrayList[position]  after that currentItem getting specific id and after that we call specific objetc id to doument firebase addsnapshot listener so how can i get on other method or adapter class? can you tell me excetly

Comment: then make a hashMap for matchKey and listeners like this val keys = hashMapOf<String, ValueEventListener?> , and when adding for listeners put match key and its listener in this, and before setting new listeners do check if listeners for this key is there or not if its there then return if not put it in and apply listeners. also make sure you are not applying listeners multiple times

Comment: i try that way but it still not working conflict is on when fire base listener notify